# Laravel - How to get last record from a table and update another table

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.8. I have this function in my api controller

```php
$bill=new Bill();
$bill->msisdn =$msisdn;
$bill->trans_id =$transReference;
$bill->ext_id =$ref_id;
$bill->amount=$game_check->amount;
$bill->answer=$useroption;
$bill->game_code=$useresponse;
$bill->is_complete_transactions  =1;
$bill->billing_channel="Unity-7799";
$bill->save();
```

I have another table user_response, the model class is User_Response. It has these fields:
id, msisdn, answer, answer_code

I want to get the last record from **$bill=new Bill()** where $bill->msisdn is equal to msisdn in User_Response. Then update answer in User_Response with $bill->answer.

Please how do I achieve this?

Comment: hello, $bill= new Bill(); is in foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

So `save()` method always return the recently save data in database.
if you do `$bill->save()`
so the last inserted record can be achive by the same object you trigger `save()` from.

For eg i need last inserted id from the database after insertion.
so

```
$bill = new Bill();
$bill->myFileds = $request->myfields;
$bill->save();
$lastInsertedId = $bill->id;
```

as you can see from above code. the last inserted record is `$bill`. you can use it for User_Repsonse

```
User_Response::where('msisdn',$bill->msisdn)->update(['answer'=>$bill->answer]);
```

Here you go